# How to integrate aws Lex chatbot to my node.js website without using Kommunicate or any other service

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, chatbot

I am new to cloud computing. I have never worked with AWS Services so I am seriously very confused about this topic.

I have created a AWS Lex Chatbot but now I'm wondring how to integrate it to my website. I need to do this for a school project and am not sure how to integrate it. Pleas help. Any advice is appreciated. How do I proceed?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.